# How to get exact time of image on video?

Tags: python, image, detection, scene, moviepy

i'm working with moviepy library trying to solve this thing.

I have an image of that video in a random time, now I need to process the video and get the  time where that image is, because i need to make a clip a few seconds before that time.

It's possible ? Do i need another Library ?

The image is this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMmsL.png)

And i need to know in which moment this image is on the video.

Thanks !

Comment: Share the relevant part of your current code. Show which variables you have and what information you want to extract from them. It is currently e.g. unclear what it means to _"have an image of that video in a random time"_

Comment: If you get the frame number, you could divide by the frame rate of the video and get the time in seconds into the video that frame appears

Comment: @zvone Hi, thanks for the answer, the important part of this, is that i have a video and a image of that video, and i need to know in what time that happen; like the image is in the second 10 of the video.

Comment: @AxelVazquez Thank you for the explanation, but what I wanted to say with my comment was that your question is not good enough and you have to show your code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info. As it is, the question is off-topic.